# I was wondering if there is any other solution to this problem. JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Given a string, return a new string where the first and last chars have been exchanged.

Examples

```
frontBack('code') → eodc
frontBack('a') → a
frontBack('ab') → ba
```

//Code

```
function frontBack(str){

    let first = str.charAt(0);
    let last = str.charAt(str.length-1);
    let newStr = str.slice(1, str.length-1);

    if (str.length == 1) {`enter code here`
        return str;
    }
    else {
        return last + newStr + first;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression and capture the first and last character, then replace them with each other. Thanks to @Ivar for pointing out a simplification:

```js
const frontBack = str => str.replace(
  /(.)(.*)(.)$/g, '$3$2$1'
);

console.log(
  frontBack('code'),
  frontBack('a'),
  frontBack('ab')
);
```

If there's only one character in the input, it won't get matched, so it'll be returned unchanged.

If there are two or more characters in the input, the first character will be captured, and the middle capture group will expand only as needed so that the final capture group and its one character touches the end of the string.

---

You could also turn it into an array and replace both ends at the same time:

```js
const frontBack = str => {
  const arr = [...str];
  [arr[0], arr[arr.length - 1]] = [arr[arr.length - 1], arr[0]];
  return arr.join('');
};

console.log(
  frontBack('code'),
  frontBack('a'),
  frontBack('ab')
);
```

But your current code is a fine solution too.

Comment: I don't think you need the positive lookahead, optional quantifier and the global flag here. If the last character is not optional, it will always capture the last character (and therefor exclude it from the second capturing group). `str.replace(/(.)(.*)(.)/, '$3$2$1')` would work too.

Comment: Unfortunately, the input of `frontBack('a'),` must turn into `'a'`. The edge case makes it a lot more complicated than would be nice.

Comment: `/(.)(.*)(.)/` needs to match at least two characters, so in case there is no match, it simply doesn't replace it/remains as is.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Yeah, that's a great idea, I was thinking it had to match regardless to go through the logic, but 1 character doesn't need to match

Answer (score 0):

```
const frontBack = (str = '') => `${str.charAt(0)}${str.slice(1, str.length - 1)}${str.charAt(str.length - 1)}`;
```

For example.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. It’s truly appreciated it.